# How to properly use multiple :not selectors using variables

Tags: jquery

I have these 3 variables , and i need to use all 3 in a :not selector

```
  var donotcountS = 'td.player:contains(S)';  
  var donotcountI = 'td.player:contains(I)';  
  var donotcountO = 'td.player:contains(O)';
```

Here i have a snippet of my script , where i have 1 variable working fine, but when i add the 2nd or 3rd it doesn't work

```
if ($(this).find("td.player:not("+donotcountS+")").length
```

I have tried these and none have worked

```
if ($(this).find("td.player:not("+donotcountS+"):not("+donotcountI+"):not("+donotcountO+")").length
if ($(this).find("td.player:not("+donotcountS+"),("+donotcountI+"),("+donotcountO+")").length
if ($(this).find("td.player:not("+donotcountS+","+donotcountI+","+donotcountO+")").length
```

Also , on another note.....currently my variables are td.player:contains() , i would like to get more specific. How can i write those , so that td.player hasClass span , that contains() ?

Comment: Working fine in this example: https://jsfiddle.net/lmgonzalves/zqu3eqfm/

Comment: cant get working https://jsfiddle.net/zqu3eqfm/8/

Comment: Your fiddle don't work because you have `0` (zero) instead `O`. Check here: https://jsfiddle.net/lmgonzalves/zqu3eqfm/10/

Comment: What is expected result ? Can include `html` at Question ?

Comment: I added my html to this fiddle to show it not working https://jsfiddle.net/zqu3eqfm/31/

Comment: Your jQuery code in the fiddle actually work! You need to fix the HTML markup (add `table` and `tr` tags). Also, all of your `tds` contains at least the `O` character. If you remove `S, O and I`, then the `td` will be removed. See here: https://jsfiddle.net/lmgonzalves/zqu3eqfm/525/

Answer (score 0):

To select elements that contain a certain `class` inside a selector, you can use the [Attribute Contains Word Selector](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/) and combine it with `:not` to do what you want, for example:

```
var donotcountClassTest = "[class~='test']";
```

You can play with this minimal example:

https://jsfiddle.net/lmgonzalves/zqu3eqfm/12/

Comment: no idea how that works with what i have  var donotcountS = 'td.player:contains(S)';  would be what exactly ?